# LC_CTYPE breaking autocomplete: what is the cause of this problem?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, locale

For some reason today, every time I hit tab in the terminal, this shows up:

```
cat bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_CA)

Display all 150 possibilities? (y or n)
```

This particular one happens when I type `cat` then hit TAB. I never changed any setting or anything. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is `en_CA` (i.e. Canadian English) a locale you expected to be in?

Comment: can you post the output of the `locale` command?

Comment: Are you sure that `en_CA` is a valid locale (that is, it both exists on your system, and has been generated by `localedef` or some similar locale generation tool)?

Comment: If you want a correct answer, please answer the question from @penguin359 , and tell how you are connected on your system (directly on the console or remotely with `ssh` or `putty`.

Answer (score 8):

I have a hunch that something your bash_completion is causing this to happen. Try clearing out your bash completion temporarily (until you exit) by doing:

```
complete -r
```

If that clears it up then it's something with bash completion, if not it still might be one of the bash built-ins

Comment: Tried this solution last, because the others seemed like a more appropriate solution to a problem that had persisted for ages, but this was the one that worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when connecting via SSH to a remote server (after having installed oh-my-zsh on my local, but I'm not sure that's relevant).

To fix it, on my local machine, I edited the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, commenting out the SendEnv line.

```
#SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Tab completion now works without the warning on the remote machine.

> bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problem on my ubuntu server (FlexiScale) and searched for a solution for a while but could not find anything suitable... Still not sure if what I did is the "right way", but it seems to work.

The warning I was seeing was:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)
```

To make sure the locales are up-to-date I did this (not sure if this was neccessary):

```
# locale-gen --purge
```

`locale` on my system was showing `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` which didn't look right to me, so I've changed my `/etc/default/locale` to look like this:

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

(I've added the second line.) After re-login the warnings were gone.

Comment: Fixing `LC_CTYPE` to be a valid value did it. You don't need `LANG` (and in fact [I recommend against it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all/15334#15334)). You can see the valid locale names on your system by running `locale -a`. On Ubuntu, run `sudo localegen xx_YY` to generate the `xx_YY` locale (assuming it can be generated).

Answer (score 1):

If you get error/warning message similar to this when press Tab for bash command autocompletion :

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (id_ID.UTF-8)
```

Solution is:

1. Install the required locale. In my case this is the "id" :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install language-pack-id
   ```
2. Reconfigure locales:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

Now bash Tab completion should work just fine. :-)

Source: http://ubuntucomputing.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-error-bash-warning-setlocale.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I had tried some of the solutions here, but when I tried to run `locale-gen`, my system said it couldn't find the command. It turns out that it's a part of the `locales` package that I didn't have installed. So I installed it, ran `locales-gen`, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Solved permanently with creating file

```
/etc/default/locale
```

With contents

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

[See answer at github](https://github.com/ejholmes/vagrant-heroku/issues/9)