# set LC_* but not LC_ALL

Tags: environment-variables, locale

I'd like to have a German (Austria) locale (A4 paper size, 24 hour time, yyyy-mm-dd), but an English-language user interface (I don't like poor translations). I figured that the correct way to achieve this is to set the `LC_` variables as follows in my `.bashrc` (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_$everythingelse=de_AT.UTF-8
```

Is there a more elegant way to set LC_$everythingelse rather than setting every single value? Setting LC_ALL is not an option, since it takes precedence over LC_MESSAGES:

```
$ export LC_ALL=de_AT.UTF_8
$ export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF_8
$ echo $LC_MESSAGES
en_US.UTF_8
$ locale | grep LC_MESSAGES
LC_MESSAGES="de_AT.UTF_8"
```

<sub>PS: It's a shared machine and I'm not sudoer, so changing system-wide settings is not an option.</sub>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are three sets of locale settings¹:

- `LANG`, the fallback setting, if you haven't specified a value for a category. It's indended for users to indicate their locale in a simple way.
- `LC_xxx` for each category (`xxx` can be `MESSAGES`, `TIME`, etc.).
- `LC_ALL` overrides all settings. It's a way for applications to override all settings in order to work in a known locale (usually `C`, the default locale), typically so that various commands produce output in a known format.

So you can set `LANG=de_AT.UTF-8` and `LC_MESSAGES=C` (`C` is the default locale and means untranslated; `en_US` is usually identical to `C` for messages).

However, there are two categories where I don't recommend changing the default, because it breaks a lot of programs:

- `LC_COLLATE` is the character [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) order. It's not very useful because it only indicates how to sort characters, not how to sort strings. Tools that know how to sort strings don't use `LC_COLLATE`. Furthermore a lot of tools expect things like “`[a-z]` matches all 26 ASCII lowercase letters and no other ASCII characters”, but that's not true in most non-default locales (try `echo B | LC_COLLATE=en_US grep '[a-z]'`).
- `LC_NUMERIC` indicates how to display numbers. In particular, in many languages, it makes floating point numbers use a `,` rather than `.` as the decimal point. But most programs that parse numbers expect a `.` and treat a `,` as a field separator.

So I recommend to

- either explicitly `LC_COLLATE=C LC_NUMERIC=_C`,
- or leave `LANG` unset and only set a value for the useful categories (`LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_TIME`, `LC_PAPER`, plus `LC_CTYPE` (whose value may vary depending on your terminal)).

¹ 
<sub>Plus [`LANGUAGE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-gettextized-software.html#Using-gettextized-software) with GNU libc. If you hadn't heard about it, you're not missing much.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the explanations! I will try a localized LC_NUMERIC, though, since the numpad on German keyboards has a `,` in place of a `.` (unfortunately), so entering numbers with a dot is inconvenient (and most apps seem to work nicely with a non-standard LC_NUMERIC). I do not fully understand your LC_COLLATE example: On my system, the example you gave does *not* match `B`.

Comment: @Heinzi [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980)

Answer (score 10):

The [man page locale(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/locale) says:

> the default locale *[...]* is determined using the following steps:
>
> 1. If there is a non-null environment variable LC_ALL, the value of LC_ALL is used.
> 2. If an environment variable with the same name as one of the
>      categories [LC_*] above exists and is non-null, its value is used for that category.
> 3. If there is a non-null environment variable LANG, the value of LANG is used.

So, you can use LANG as a sort of low-precedence analogue of
LC_ALL: set the value of LANG to `de_AT` and LC_MESSAGES to `en_US`:

```
$ env LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=de_AT.UTF-8 locale | egrep '(MESSAGES|PAPER)'
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="de_AT.UTF-8"
```