# Why are capital letters included in a range of lower-case letters in an awk regex?

Tags: regular-expression, awk

```
$ echo ABC | awk '$0 ~ /^[a-b]/'
ABC
$ echo ABC | awk '$0 ~ /^[a-a]/'
$ echo ABC | awk '$0 ~ /^a/'
$
```

You see. `/[a-b]/` captures `A`, but `/[a-a]/` or `/a/` doesn't. Why?

Comment: See [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980) for more (unresolved) info on this topic.

Comment: This appears to be more than just a simple(?) LC_COLLATE issue, because using *some* non-C values for LC_COLLATE produces different results, depending on which utility is used. eg. 'sed' and 'grep' give different results to 'awk' when using LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8 or en_US.UTF-8 ... sed and grep manage to resolve the case issue, and only lower-case is printed (using the same values as above)

Comment: At least in gawk (GNU Awk) this has been fixed ([a-z] matches only lowercase letters) since version 4.0: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges-and-Locales.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a "locale" problem, I think.

In my locale, it_IT, the following snippet

```
if [[ a < A ]]; then
  echo "a < A"
elif [[ a > A ]]; then
  echo "a > A"
else
  echo "a = A"
fi

if [[ b < A ]]; then
  echo "b < A"
elif [[ b > A ]]; then
  echo "b > A"
else
  echo "b = A"
fi
```

shows

```
a < A
b > A
```

so that `A` is (surprisingly) between `a` and `b`, so in the range.

Try executing

```
echo ABC | LC_COLLATE=C awk '$0 ~ /^[a-b]/'
```

**Edit**

the following command shows the collating order in your locale:

```
echo $(LC_COLLATE=C printf '%s\n' {A..z} | sort)
```

the output on my machine is

```
` ^ _ [ ] a A b B c C d D e E f F g G h H i I j J k K l L m M n N o O p P q Q r R s S t T u U v V w W x X y Y z Z
```

(cannot understand from bash's manual page if *sequence expressions* are expanded in locale collating order or not; it seems not).

Comment: +1, but you just need LC_COLLATE, not LC_ALL, for this particular case.

Comment: @mattdm: you're right, i'm lazy

Comment: @enzotib: I am puzzled... This idea seems to mean that every time I want to set a range /[a-x]/, I must use LC_COLLATE....What on earth has a collating sequence got to do identifying what is Upper-case vs Lower case? ... I can't see how a Collating sequence dictates what is upper case and what isn't... I keep grappling with these locale issues, and am slowly making headway, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: @fred: frequently, when using `sort`, `join` or the like, I start my scripts with `export LC_COLLATE=C`. Now I have to start this way also scripts using `awk` :)

Comment: I've followed the link in Caleb's comment (worth readng). I can now see a bit of light here, but none-the-less, it still *seems* that something is amiss or at least 'not as expected'. Relying on a collation order to determine case simply doesn't make sense. I **think** this excerpt from The Single UNIX Spec (old) is notable: *"Portable applications must not use range expressions, even though all implementations support them."*. In this context, does this suggest that a **range expression** has, by definiton, side-stepped the notion of case! It deals in ranges, not case.. QED! (I think :)

Comment: @enzotib Why did you use `LC_COLLATE=C` with your `printf` command in the edit?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: it is inessential indeed, but to be sure that `printf` interpret the sequence `{A..z}` in a way independent of the particular locale (as the sentence following explains in some way: "cannot understand from bash's manual page if sequence expressions are expanded in locale collating order or not; it seems not".

Comment: I see. And I also see they are not (but I share your worries in that matter). And... I don't agree with @mattdm's first comment, because if `LC_ALL` was set in the environment, then changing `LC_COLLATE` alone would have no effect.

Comment: The sequence eval order doesn't matter *in this case* since you sort after the sequence is generated. However, your example would work more accurately with LC_COLLATE next to sort: "echo $(printf '%s\n' {A..z} | LC_COLLATE='C' sort)" ... which would contrast correctly with the default case "echo $(printf '%s\n' {A..z} | LC_COLLATE='' sort)". The original syntax above never actually applies the locally modified LC_COLLATE to the sort command [of course, all bets are off if LC_ALL was set somewhere...]

Comment: @Peter.O [a-z] doesn't have anything to do with case. It's the list of characters between a and z inclusive, with "between" being defined as sort order so Swedes get ä after the other letters, as per their alphabet, and Germans get it mixed in with a, as normal for German. Most non-programmers would put B between a and z, for example, apples Berlin zeppelin, not apples zeppelin Berlin, so [a-z] includes B in most locales.

Comment: Surprisingly [`sort` and `[a-z]` may yield different results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578053/108618).