# Sort behaves strangely on case sensitive sorting

Tags: linux, sort

Sort is sorting differently than I would expect. I have this file, call it `text.txt`:

```
a   1
A   1
a   11
```

(the space is always one `\t`)

I want to sort them alphabetically by the first column. However, when I do

`sort -k 1 text.txt`

all I got is the text.txt file, not sorted. If I do it by the deprecated `+ -` notation, meaning

`sort +0 -1 text.txt`

it works as it should, meaning that I get this output:

```
a   1
a   11
A   1
```

This strange behaviour occurs only when I have lines that differs only by case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the default locale, `A` would be before `a`. Most locales have a weird collation order; it's often best to keep `LC_COLLATE=C`. On this issue, see [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980) [Why are capital letters included in a range of lower-case letters in an awk regex?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19322)

Comment: This issue, however, stands with LC_COLLATE=C (I think, I don't have a shell here now), the problem was really in the columns... however.... it probably should not be. I don't know. I will test it tomorrow. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the end column, too:

```
$ sort -k1,1 text.txt
a       1
a       11
A       1
```

To quote the [GNU sort man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort):

> ```
>    -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>           start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default  end  of
>           line)
> ```

Comment: Oh. I guess I should have RTFM more carefully :) Thanks.

Comment: It is really strange that this was needed - the `POS2` is evidently **optional**. Maybe a bug in `sort`?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz, yes, it is optional. No, it is not a bug. POS2 is optional, but when you don't specify it then the default is used, i.e. the key then contains all columns up to the next newline.

Answer (score 2):

You most certainly hit upon a bug in `sort`! If you had no spaces in the file, there would be no way to sort it properly:

```
$ cat aaa
a1
A1
a11

$ sort aaa
a1
A1
a11

$ sort -k1,1 aaa
a1
A1
a11
```

Even more visible with the following:

```
$ cat bbb
A B b 0
a B b 0
A b b 1

$ sort bbb
a B b 0
A B b 0
A b b 1

$ sort -k1,2 bbb
a B b 0
A b b 1
A B b 0
```

Comment: That behaviour is correct, though. I think.

Comment: Not a bug, but a collation locale issue: Karel clearly has a `$LC_LOCALE` that is not `POSIX`, since `A` isn't before `a`. On this issue, see [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980) [Why are capital letters included in a range of lower-case letters in an awk regex?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19322)

Comment: @Gilles The problem isn't just that `A` is before or after `a` - it is that in *some cases* it is treated as before, in other as after.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Exactly, this is consistent with a locale where `a` and `A` are equivalent.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, so I understand now that the problem is with locale, not `sort` itself - but two letters being defined as *equivalent*? This is absurd! Who and why ever came up with this?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Think case insensitive sorts. And `à` = `à` (U+00E0 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE = U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A, U+0300 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT). And in some languages (e.g. French), `là` is sorted after `la` but before `label`. `sort` doesn't get everything right because it performs a lexicographic sort (which, despite the etymology, is not what dictionaries do), but it tries to go a little beyond the basics. The results aren't so great (I keep `LC_COLLATE=C` myself).

Comment: @Gilles Case insensitive sorts would be nice as an option in some cases - but not as the default for locales like `en_US.UTF-8`! Furthermore, the case is even more complicated than this. The simple test suggested [in this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/why-are-capital-letters-included-in-a-range-of-lower-case-letters-in-an-awk-regex/19327#19327) prints, depending on locale, either `A > a` or `a < A` but never `A = a`. Yet, the `sort` aliasing...