# How to find out if PWD contains spaces or non-English letters?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I created an environment variable:

```
WD=`pwd`
```

How can I check if it contains spaces or non-English letters?

Comment: Can you clarify how you define English letters ? (i.e are digits acceptable, punctuation, any ASCII, ...) as your question has triggered various differing interpretations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that by “non-English letters” you mean letters other than the 26 unadorned letters of the Latin alphabet. Then, strictly speaking, here's a test that meets your requirements:

```
if tmp=${WD//[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]/};
   [[ $tmp = *[[:alpha:] ]* ]]; then
  # $WD contains letters other than A-Z and a-z or a space
```

That is, strip the English letters and see if there are any letters or spaces left.

I suspect that you're in fact trying to avoid all non-ASCII characters and all whitespace, including the ones that aren't letters such as `¿` or `£` or `٣`. You can do that by matching the characters that are not `!` through `~` (i.e. the ASCII characters other than whitespace):

```
if (LC_ALL=C; [[ $WD = *[^!-~]* ]]) then …
```

Note that [ranges like `!-~` or `A-Z` don't always do what you'd expect when you have `LC_COLLATE` set.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges) Hence we set `LC_ALL` to a known value (`LC_ALL` trumps all [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) settings).

If you're checking for “unusual” characters in files (why else exclude even spaces, which are allowed on most modern platforms), it might make sense to have a more restricted lists that doesn't allow any nonportable characters. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276) only allows ASCII letters, digits and `-._`.

```
if (LC_ALL=C; [[ $WD = *[^-._0-9A-Za-z]* ]]) then …
```

Comment: That first test would be a lot simpler as `[[ -n "${WD//[a-zA-Z ]}" ]] && echo "I have special characters"`

Comment: @Patrick. The first test is like that otherwise it would be subject to possible problems. Gilles' link, and further links on that page, explain it.  

The bottom line is that a **range** is not necessarily what **you** think the *range* is. 

The English `a` and `z` are just two chars to the computer, and the **range** between them is not necessarily *an immutable contiguous 26 letter alphabet*. 

Yes, they are contiguous as an ASCII or UNICODE range, but in a regex range statement, the **range** is based on the collating sequence

Comment: @Patrick That wouldn't work with many `LC_COLLATE` settings. You can kill `LC_COLLATE` while retaining `LC_CTYPE`, taking care of `LC_ALL` and `LANGUAGE`, but it's a lot more complicated than just listing the exact set of characters you want.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions and `grep` is what are you looking for.

We match any non-English letter or digit or `/` (because it's a part of every path).

```
if [[ -n "$( pwd | grep -o -P "([^a-zA-Z0-9\/])*" )" ]]; then 
    echo "error"
fi
```

`sed` could be usable in that case too.

If may replace all correct symbols in `${WD}` with `''` and look if something is left. If resulting string have non-zero length - `${WD}` is not correct.

So, if we are expecting only `/`, numbers and English letters.

```
if [[ -n "$( pwd | sed -r -e 's/([a-zA-Z0-9\/])*//g' )" ]]; then 
    echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: You'll probably want to allow `.` in the path too.

Comment: There is nothing about it in the question.

Comment: This won't work in most `LC_COLLATE` settings (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25162/885) for explanation). Plus all punctuation and symbols were supposed to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is slightly simpler than `grep` or `sed` in that case:

```
if [[ -n "$(echo $WD|tr -d '[:alnum:]/')" ]];then
  echo "gotcha"
fi
```

Comment: This won't work in most character sets, where `[:alnum:]` contains non-English letters. Plus all digits, punctuation and symbols were supposed to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pattern `[a-z]` is case-insensitive, so just as simple as:

```
[ -z "${PWD//[a-z\/]}" ] || echo "Bad chars in path: ${PWD//[a-z\/]}"
```

Comment: This won't work in most `LC_COLLATE` settings (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25162/885) for explanation). Plus all punctuation and symbols were supposed to be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Bash can do its own pattern matching.

```
if [[ ${WD} = *[^[:alnum:]/]* ]]; then
  echo 'Baaaad.'
fi
```

Comment: This won't work in most character sets, where `[:alnum:]` contains non-English letters. Plus all digits, punctuation and symbols were supposed to be allowed.