# terminal: non-english characters

Tags: ubuntu, character-encoding, gnome-terminal, locale

I used to be able to copy&paste (or type if I load respective keyboard layout)
any kind of characters (eg. é ö ñ ß و 好) in my console/terminal.

Now I bought a new computer and it does not work any more, only English/ASCII characters (but in other programs, e.g. firefox, it still works).

Distribution: Ubuntu. Terminals tried: gnome-terminal, xterm, konsole.

I tried [setting LANG in /etc/environment to en_US.UTF-8](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#My_terminal_doesn.27t_support_UTF-8) but after reboot `echo $LANG` still gives `C`. I also tried setting `Character encoding` to `Unicode(UTF-8)` in the gnome-terminal `Terminal`-menu - without effect.

Question: How can I get a terminal that is able to deal with non-English characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Locales are built upon request, because they can take a lot of space. You need to activate the locale by generating the associated data. Ubuntu undoubtedly has a GUI where you can set this, but I don't know where it is offhand. Run this once and for all in a terminal:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

You may need to log out and back in for the `LANG` value not to be sanitized down to C, but you should be able to test right now by running `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gnome-terminal`.

By the way, I recommend `LC_CTYPE` instead of `LANG`. `LC_CTYPE` controls the character set only; `LANG` also affects other locale categories, in particular collation (i.e. character ordering), which [can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges) cause trouble occasionally.

Comment: `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` printed `Generating locales...`
 ` en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date`
`Generation complete.`, but after `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gnome-terminal` in the new terminal it still prints only question marks.

Comment: From what I can see Ubuntu has adopted the [Debian way](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/locale-gen.8.html) (`/etc/locale.gen`) since then.

Answer (score 2):

If you get your locales installed system-wide, try to set up fonts, that can display such a rare characters. There is a problem in Ubuntu in native console, when you have your locales set as `UTF8_ru` and `UTF8_en`, you can't type Russian, cause you need to set up Cyrillic fonts for that. So you need `UTF8_yourlocale` locale set up and appropriate console fonts installed.

And Mozilla, OO and other have their own localization packages, so it gives no effect for system-wide locale settings.

PS: Of course I may be wrong.

Comment: And how to detect which of the fonts support my language? Is `fc-list :lang=en` correct for this?