# Alphabetizing names in `ls` alias with .files not intermingled

Tags: linux, ls, sort, locale, dot-files

I am currently using the following `ls` alias: `alias ls='ls -alhGkpsq --color=auto'`. This results in following directory listing.

```
[03:35] bryson@brys  ~ :$ ls
total 48K
4.0K drwx------ 4 bryson 4.0K Nov  2 03:34 ./
8.0K drwxr-xr-x 3 root   4.0K Apr 19  2012 ../
4.0K -rw------- 1 bryson  676 Nov  2 03:35 .bash_history
8.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 bryson   21 Nov 23  2011 .bash_logout
8.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 bryson   57 Nov 23  2011 .bash_profile
4.0K -rw------- 1 bryson   50 Nov  2 03:34 .lesshst
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 3 bryson 4.0K Nov  2 03:21 source/
4.0K drwx------ 2 bryson 4.0K Nov  2 03:23 .ssh/
4.0K -rw------- 1 bryson 1.6K Nov  2 03:23 .viminfo
```

The issue I have with this, which is *not* an issue with OS X's version of `ls`, is that `.ssh/` is alphabetized *ignoring the `.`* in the filename.

What I would like is for `ls` to alphabetize the dot files all together at the top, which is where it puts `.` and `..` as well. (Arch Linux, Bash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably caused by your locale, but if you do:

`LC_COLLATE=C ls -F --color=auto -l`

The dot files are sorted correctly

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more specifically why this works?

Comment: Try reading up on LOCALE settings

Comment: You can find some information about collating in: [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980/606)