# Why does [A-Z] match lowercase letters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, locale

In all shells I am aware of, `rm [A-Z]*` removes all files that start with an uppercase letter, but with bash this removes all files that start with a letter.

As this problem exists on Linux and Solaris with bash-3 and bash-4, it cannot be a bug caused by a buggy pattern matcher in libc or a miss-configured locale definition.

Is this strange and risky behavior intended or is this just a bug that exists unfixed since many years?

Comment: What does `locale` output? I cannot reproduce this (`touch foo; echo [A-Z]*` outputs the literal pattern, not "foo", in an otherwise empty directory).

Comment: Considering how many people have said it works for them, or have shown examples of how LC_COLLATE affects this, maybe you could edit your question to add a sample bash session which illustrates exactly the scenario you're asking about. Please include the bash version that you're using.

Comment: If you did read all the text here you would know what bash version I use and what I did since I already posted the solution to my question. Let me repeat the solution: bash does not manage it's own locale so that setting LC_COLLATE does not change anything until you start another bash process with the new environment.

Comment: See also [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges) (but that question wasn't specifically about bash)

Comment: "setting LC_COLLATE does not change anything until you start another bash process with the new environment."  That doesn't match the behavior I see with bash-4 on Solaris.  It is changing the behavior in the running shell.  `# echo [A-Z]* ; export LC_COLLATE=C ; echo [A-Z]*`
A b B z Z 
A B Z

Comment: Which bash4 on which Solaris?

Comment: 4.1.11(2) on SunOS 5.11 (x86).   Same behavior on bash 3.2.25(1) on CentOS 5.7

Comment: There must be something really strange as I recently run bash under `truss -ulibc::setlocale` and the first try to change LC_COLLATE did not call setlocale() the second try did. Since then, all test work as they should. Even if I call another new bash with the previous LC_* setup that originally includes lower case characters in [A-Z]. I would usually believe that I did something wrong, but then the case where starting another bash could not make a difference and Stephané did also observe that setlocale was not called, so this cannot be based on wrong usage.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't the case statement (in bash) case-sensitive when nocasematch is off?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10695029/3960947)  (on Stack Overflow)

Comment: @schily, sorry my bad, [I had messed up my test cases](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/is-file-globbing-in-bash-buggy-or-is-there-a-strange-rule-in-bash/227076?noredirect=1#comment386049_227084)

Answer (score 73):

> Note that when using range expressions like [a-z], letters of the other case may be included, depending on the setting of LC_COLLATE.

`LC_COLLATE` is a variable which determines the collation order used when sorting the results of pathname expansion, and determines the behavior of range expressions,  equivalence classes,  and collating sequences within pathname expansion and pattern matching.

---

Consider the following:

```
$ touch a A b B c C x X y Y z Z
$ ls
a  A  b  B  c  C  x  X  y  Y  z  Z
$ echo [a-z] # Note the missing uppercase "Z"
a A b B c C x X y Y z
$ echo [A-Z] # Note the missing lowercase "a"
A b B c C x X y Y z Z
```

Notice when the command `echo [a-z]` is called, the expected output would be all files with lower case characters. Also, with `echo [A-Z]`, files with uppercase characters would be expected.

---

Standard collations with locales such as `en_US` have the following order:

```
aAbBcC...xXyYzZ
```

- Between `a` and `z` (in `[a-z]`) are ALL uppercase letters, except for `Z`.
- Between `A` and `Z` (in `[A-Z]`) are ALL lowercase letters, except for `a`.

See:

```
     aAbBcC[...]xXyYzZ
     |              |
from a      to      z

     aAbBcC[...]xXyYzZ
      |              |
from  A     to       Z
```

If you change the `LC_COLLATE` variable to `C` it looks as expected:

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ echo [a-z]
a b c x y z
$ echo [A-Z]
A B C X Y Z
```

So, it's **not a bug**, it's a **collation issue**.

---

Instead of range expressions you can use POSIX defined [character classes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01), such as `upper` or `lower`. They work also with different `LC_COLLATE` configurations and even with **accented characters**:

```
$ echo [[:lower:]]
a b c x y z à è é
$ echo [[:upper:]]
A B C X Y Z
```

Comment: If this behavior was controllable by LC_* environment variables, I did not ask. I work in the POSIX standard committee and I know of collating problems with e.g. `tr`so this is what I checked first.

Comment: @schily I cannot reproduce your problem with neither an old bash-3 or a bash-4; both are controllable via `LC_COLLATE` which is also documented in the manual.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce what you believe, but see my own answer...From the ideas in this discussion I discovered the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 25):

`[A-Z]` in `bash` matches all collating elements (characters but call also be sequence of characters like `Dsz` in Hungarian locales) that sort after `A` and sort before `Z`. In your locale, `c` probably sorts in-between B and C.

```
$ printf '%s\n' A a á b B c C Ç z Z Ẑ | sort
a
A
á
b
B
c
C
Ç
z
Z
Ẑ
```

So `c` or `z` would be matched by `[A-Z]`, but not `Ẑ` or `a`.

```
$ printf '%s\n' A a á b B c C Ç z Z Ẑ |
pipe>  bash -c 'while IFS= read -r x; do case $x in [A-Z]) echo "$x"; esac; done'
A
á
b
B
c
C
Ç
z
Z
```

In the C locale, the order would be:

```
$ printf '%s\n' A a á b B c C Ç z Z Ẑ | LC_COLLATE=C sort
A
B
C
Z
a
b
c
z
Ç
á
Ẑ
```

So `[A-Z]` would match `A`, `B`, `C`, `Z`, but not `Ç` and still not `Ẑ`.

If you want to match on upper-case letters (in any script), you can use `[[:upper:]]` instead. There's no builtin way in `bash` to only match uppercase letters in the *latin* script (except by listing them individually).

If you want to match the `A` to `Z` *English* letters without diacritics, you can either use `[A-Z]` or `[[:upper:]]` but in the `C` locale (assuming the data is not encoded in character sets like BIG5 or GB18030 which has several characters whose encoding *contains* the encoding of those letters) or list them individually (`[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`).

Note that there is some variation between shells.

For `zsh`, `bash -O globasciiranges` (strangely named option introduced in bash-4.3), `schily-sh` and `yash`, `[A-Z]` matches on the characters whose code point is between that of `A` and that of `Z`, so would be equivalent to the behaviour of `bash` in the C locale.

For ash, mksh and ancient shells, same as `zsh` above but limited to single-byte charsets. That is, in a UTF-8 locale for instance, `[É-Ź]` would not match on `Ó`, but since that's `[<c3><89>-<c5><b9>]`, that would match on byte values 0x89 to 0xc5!

`ksh93` behaves like `bash` except that it treats as special cases ranges whose ends both start with lowercase letters or uppercase letters. In that case, it only matches on collating elements that sort between those ends, but that are (or their first character for multi-character collating elements) *also* lowercase (or uppercase respectively). So `[A-Z]` there would match on `É`, but not on `e` as `e` does sort between `A` and `Z` but is not uppercase like `A` and `Z`.

For `fnmatch()` patterns (as in `find -name '[A-Z]'`) or system regular expressions (as in `grep '[A-Z]'`), it depends on the system and locale. For instance, on a GNU system here, `[A-Z]` doesn't match on `x` in the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale, but it does in the `th_TH.UTF-8` one. It's unclear to me what information it uses to determine that, but [it is apparently based on a lookup table derived from LC_COLLATE locale data](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2010-09/msg00070.html)).

All behaviours are allowed by POSIX as POSIX leaves the behaviour of ranges unspecified in locales other than the C locale. Now we can argue over the benefits of each approach.

`bash`'s approach makes a lot of sense as with `[C-G]`, we want the characters in between `C` and `G`. And using the user's sort order for what determines what's *in-between* is the most logical approach.

Now, the problem is that it breaks the expectations of a lot of people, especially those people used to the traditional behaviour of pre-Unicode, even pre-internationalisation days. While from a normal user, it makes may sense that `[C-I]` includes `h` as the `h` letter is between `C` and `I` and that `[A-g]` does not include `Z`, it's a different matter for people having dealt with ASCII only for decades.

That `bash` behaviour is also different from the `[A-Z]` range matching in other GNU tools like in GNU regular expressions (as in `grep`/`sed`...) or `fnmatch()` as in `find -name`.

It also means that what `[A-Z]` matches varies with the environment, with the OS and with the version of the OS. The fact that `[A-Z]` matches Á but not Ź is also suboptimal.

For `zsh`/`yash`, we use a different sorting order. Instead of relying on the user's notion of character order, we use the character point code values. That has the benefit of being easy to understand, but from a practical point of few, outside of ASCII, it is not very useful. `[A-Z]` matches the 26 US-english upper-case letters, `[0-9]` matches decimal digits. There are code points in Unicode that follow the order of some alphabets but that's not generalised and can't be generalised as anyway different people using a same script do not necessarily agree on the order of letters.

For traditional shells and mksh, dash, it's broken (now that most people use multi-byte characters), but primarily because they don't have multi-byte support yet. Adding multi-byte support to shells like `bash` and `zsh` has been a huge effort and is still ongoing. `yash` (a Japanese shell) was initially designed with multi-byte support from the start.

ksh93's approach has the benefit to be consistent with the system's regular expressions or fnmatch() (or at least appears to at least on GNU systems). There, it doesn't break some people's expectation as `[A-Z]` doesn't include lower case letters, `[A-Z]` includes `É` (and Á, but not Ź). It's not consistent with `sort` or generally `strcoll()` order.

Comment: If you were right, this could be controlled via LC_* variables. There seems to be a different reason.

Comment: `posh` also behave like `zsh` and `yash`.

Comment: @cuonglm, more like `mksh` (both derived from pdksh). `posh -c $'case Ó in [É-Ź]) echo yes; esac'` returns nothing.

Comment: BTW: My question was against `bash`, but your reply is related to `sort`. Did you try to check file name globbing with bash-3?

Comment: @schily, I mention `sort` because `bash` globs are based on character sort order. I don't currently have access to such an old version of `bash`, but I can check later. Was it different then?

Comment: Let me mention again: zsh, POSIX-ksh88, ksh93t+ Bourne Shell, all behave the same way as I expect. Bash is the only shell that behaves different and bash is not controllable via the locale in this case.

Comment: @Stéphane - What you get with the case statement in the Bourne Shell is expected behavior assuming that you use UTF-8. The Bourne Shell uses gmatch() for case statements and this supports wide characters but does not use strcoll() but a plain value compare for the range. 0xFF is perfectly inside the range you specified.

Comment: @schily, note that `\xFF` there is the _byte_ 0xFF, not the character U+00FF (`ÿ` itself encoded as 0xC3 0xBF). `\xFF` alone doesn't form a valid character so I can't see why it should be matched by `[É-Ź]`.

Comment: @schily, having said that, it seems that `zsh` behaves the same. `yash` won't allow invalid character.

Comment: @schily, I've raised the question [on the zsh-workers mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.devel/34293)

Comment: @Stéphane - The way \xFF is handled depends on the shell internals. Given the fact that \x1234 is possible, this should explain that the shell has parts where characters are handled as wide characters and others where the shell uses multibyte characters. gmatch (that handles `case` exists in a place where the shell uses multibyte characters but inside `gmatch()` everything is temporary converted into wide characters for processing.

Comment: @schily, in that case, the \xFF was expanded to the 0xFF byte by my shell (zsh) before passing to schily-sh. schily-sh internally wrongly identified it to U+00FF. You may want to have a look at the [current discussion on the zsh ML](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.devel/34293). Note that ksh93 is a bit broken as well in that `b=$'\xff' ksh -c $'[[ $b = [\uff] ]]'` returns false but `b=$'\xff' ksh -c $'[[ $b = [[:alpha:]] ]]'` returns true.

Comment: how characters are converted from a multi byte locale depends on `mbtowc()`. If there is a character that is officially an impossible multibyte value, mbtowc() returns -1 and the string converter advances by one and the output is still what the first `wchar_t *` parameter returns.

Comment: @schily, yes the shell has to decide what to do with those bytes not forming parts of valid characters. What I'm saying is that treating them as if they were the characters whose code point has the same value as that byte value is not the best approach IMO. Hence me starting the discussion on  the zsh ML (an on the Austin group 2 months ago).

Comment: The only other way to handle this seems to drop such characters and this does not look like a better solution.

Comment: @schily, there are other ways. See [how `zsh` is now doing it](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.devel/34293/focus=34308).

Comment: @schily Yes, Bash behavior is controllable via LC_* variables. Just that the must be active in the running environment to work their magic. Start a new bash as this: `LC_COLLATE="C" bash` and try again `echo [a-z]*`. Or, more to the point, try: `LC_COLLATE="C" bash -c 'echo [a-z]*'`.

Comment: This was a little easier to see using `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | sort` and `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | LANG=C sort` and also helped me confirm my language setting is causing the collating behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score 9):

It's intended and documented in `bash` documentation, [pattern matching section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching). The range expression `[X-Y]` will be included any characters between `X` and `Y` using the current locale’s collating sequence and character set:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 bash -c 'case b in [A-Z]) echo yes; esac' 
yes
```

You can see, `b` sorted between `A` and `Z` in `en_US.utf8` locale.

You have some choices to prevent this behavior:

```
# Setting LC_ALL or LC_COLLATE to C
LC_ALL=C bash -c 'echo [A-Z]*'

# Or using POSIX character class
LC_ALL=C bash -c 'echo [[:upper:]]*'
```

or enable `globasciiranges` (with bash 4.3 and above):

```
bash -O globasciiranges -c 'echo [A-Z]*'
```

Answer (score 7):

I observed this behavior on a new Amazon EC2 instance.  Since the OP didn't offer an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll post one:

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ touch foo
$ echo [A-Z]*     # prepare for a surprise!
foo

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release
$ uname -a
Linux spinup-tmp12 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 18:36:15 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ env | grep LC_  # no locale, let's set one
$ LC_ALL=C
$ echo [A-Z]*
[A-Z]*

$ unset LC_ALL    # ok, good. what if we go back to no locale?
$ echo [A-Z]*
foo
```

So, not having my `LC_*` set leads bash 4.1.2(1)-release on Linux to produce apparently odd behavior.  I can reliably toggle the odd behavior by setting and unsetting the respective locale variables.  Unsurprisingly, this behavior appears consistent through exporting:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ bash
$ echo [A-Z]*
[A-Z]*
$ exit
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ unset LC_ALL
$ bash
$ echo [A-Z]*
foo
```

While I'm seeing bash behave as Stéphane "Shellshock" Chazelas [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227076/50240), I think the [bash documentation on pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) is buggy:

> For example, *in the **default C** locale*, ‘[a-dx-z]’ is equivalent to ‘[abcdxyz]’

I read that sentence (emphasis mine) as "if the relevant locale variables are not set, then bash will default to the C locale".  Bash does not appear to be doing that.  Instead it appears to be defaulting to a locale where the characters are sorted in dictionary order with diacritic folding:

```
$ echo [A-E]*
[A-E]*
$ echo [A-F]*
foo
$ touch "évocateur"
$ echo [A-F]*
foo évocateur
```

I think it'd be good for bash to document how it will behave when `LC_*` (specifically `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE`) are undefined.  But in the mean time, I'll share some [wisdom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72761/50240):

> ... you have to be very careful with [character ranges] because they will not produce the expected results unless properly configured. For now, you should avoid using them and use character classes instead.

and

> If you're really proper, and/or are scripting for a multi-locale environment, it's probably best to make sure you know what your locale variables are when you're matching files, or to be sure that you're coding in a completely generic way.

---

**Update** Based on @G-Man comment, let's look deeper into what's happening:

```
$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Ah, ha! That explains the collation seen earlier.  Let's remove all the locale variables:

```
$ unset LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL
$ env | grep 'LC_|LANG'
$ echo [A-Z]*
[A-Z]*
```

There we go.  Now bash operates consistently with respect to documentation on this Linux system.  If any of the locale variables are set (`LANGUAGE`, `LANG`, `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL`, etc.) then Bash uses those according to its manual.  Otherwise, bash falls back to C.

The [Wooledge bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098) has this to say:

> On recent GNU systems, the variables are used in this order.  If LANGUAGE is set, use that, unless LANG is set to C, in which case LANGUAGE is ignored. Also, some programs simply don't use LANGUAGE at all. Otherwise, if LC_ALL is set, use that. Otherwise, if the specific LC_* variable that covers this usage is set, use that. (For example, LC_MESSAGES covers error messages.) Otherwise, use LANG.

So the apparent problem, both in operation and documentation, can be explained by looking at the total sum of all locale driving variables.

Comment: If no LC_variable is present and bash does not behave as documented for the `C` locale, this is a bug.

Comment: @bishop: (1) Typo: MVCE should be MCVE.  (2) If you want your example to be complete, you should add `env | grep LANG` or `echo "$LANG"`.

Comment: @schily Further investigation convinced me there's no bug in the documentation or operation on this Linux system.

Comment: @G-Man  Thanks!  I forgot about `LANG`. With that hint, all is explained.

Comment: LANG was introduced around 1988 by Sun for the first localization attempts, before they discovered that a single variable is not sufficient.  Today it it used as a fallback and LC_ALL is used as forced overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

Locale can change what characters are matched by `[A-Z]`. Use

```
(LC_ALL=C; rm [A-Z]*)
```

to eliminate the influence. (I used a subshell to localize the change).

Comment: This does not work, it still matches all letters

Comment: This won't work because glob was done before rm executed. Try `export LC_ALL=C` first.

Comment: Sorry, you missunderstand the question that is related to bash and not to rm.

Comment: @schily: Yes, I was wrong, you have to separate the statements. Check the update.

Answer (score 2):

As has been already said, this is a "collating order" issue.

The range a-z may contain upper case letters in some locales:

```
     aAbBcC[...]xXyYzZ
     |              |
from a      to      z
```

The correct solution since bash 4.3 is to set the option `globasciiranges`:

```
shopt -s globasciiranges
```

to make bash act as if `LC_COLLATE=C` has been set in **glob**ing ranges.

Answer (score -7):

It seems that I found the right answer to my own question:

Bash is buggy as it does not manage it's own locale. So setting LC_* in a bash process is without effect in that shell process.

If you set the LC_COLLATE=C and then start another bash, the globbing works as expected in the new bash process.

Comment: Not in any of my bashes.

Comment: I don't repro this in any version of bash on my machine, it sounds like you didn't `export` it properly.

Comment: So you believe that something that is properly exported, so that it affects a new bash process is not properly exported?

Comment: I would guess that the bug is in bash and not in Solaris. It is most unlikely that Solaris has a version with patched in bugs. In order to make a setlocale working, the right values need to be in environ while calling setlocale(). If you have access to the bash sources, you may like to check whether this is done properly in bash. How did you check whether setlocale() is called? Did you use truss -u or did you check whether related files are accessed?

Comment: If you need a piece of code that is known to work, a proper setlocale setup is done in the Bourne Shell in name.c in the function dolocale().

Comment: Could you run your tests again? It suddenly started to work for me. Does it change  behavior for you too?

Comment: Sorry, I had messed up my test cases, On Solaris, I had `LC_ALL` in the environment and was only changing `LC_COLLATE`. `env -i LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 truss -t '' -u ::setlocale bash -c 'LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8; [[ c = [A-Z] ]] && echo A; LC_COLLATE=C; [[ c = [A-Z] ]] && echo B'` instead of `env -i LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8 truss -t '' -u ::setlocale bash -c 'LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8; [[ c = [A-Z] ]] && echo A; LC_COLLATE=C; [[ c = [A-Z] ]] && echo B'`. So yes, it is working correctly on both Solaris and GNU

Comment: Well I would be willing to believe that I did do something wrong as well, but then the case where starting another bash could not work. Or do you have an explanation for that case?

Comment: Setting `LC_COLLATE=C` works for me (changes the behaviour inside a single bash, not even a subshell.  (bash 4.3.30(1) on Ubuntu)).  @Schily, in your earlier test, did you maybe have `LC_ALL` set but not exported?  That would explain LC_COLLATE having no effect on the existing shell, and why starting a new process did work.

Comment: Solaris's handling of the environment is notoriously deficient, so I wouldn't be surprised if the "bug" in bash was the lack of a Solaris-specific workaround.

Comment: @schily: Do you have a citation for where changing the LC_* variables within a shell is required to cause it to update its own locale state? I would think exactly the opposite. In particular for a shell executing a script, changing locale mid-way through parsing/execution of the script would not even have well-defined behavior, as the script is a text file and "text file" is only meaningful within the context of a single character encoding.

Comment: @Peter: the window where I could check was flooded from truss -u - sorry I cannot verity this anymore.

Comment: @R..5: With locales, POSIX is currently not really ready, setlocale() sets the locale for the process and not for a thread and uselocale() and the *_l() functions have been added in 2008. I am not sure whether the needed functionality is mentioned in POSIX at all. Important here is how shells import environment and th fact that there is no `unexport`see next comment...

Comment: ksh and bash are less usable with shell variables then the Burne Shell. The Bourne Shell imports all environment variables and exports the imported value even if you do local changes. This permits you to run a script in LC_ALL=C but all started programs use the imported locale. If you later run e.g. `export LC_ALL`, the modified value of the exported variable is exported. Bash and ksh always import the environment as well, but any imported variable is automatically exported as well, so local changes are always exported.