# Double square parenthese inside grep pattern

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
grep "^[[:space:]]*clientPort[^[:alpha:]]" zoo.cfg
```

This is a grep pattern to extract the line that contains the port number from the configuration file.

1) Normally in a regex, I use square brackets to match any one of the enclosing characters. Here I am seeing `:alpha:`. Is it same as [a-zA-Z]?

2) Why there are double square parentheses in the regex?

3) `[^[:alpha:]]`, What does the carat symbol between square brackets mean?

The configuration file contains the line,

```
clientPort=2181
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) allow you to use [Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) to represent the set of collating elements. The syntax for `Bracket Expression` is `[...]`, where you can place in `...` any of collating elements, collating symbols, equivalence classes, character classes, or range expressions.

The one you use `alpha` is a character class name, made by place class name between `[:` and `:]`. So, you have used the character class expression `[:alpha:]` in between `Bracket Expression` `[[:alpha:]]`.

The character class expression is not the same as range expression `[a-zA-Z]` in some locales. [Here's the best example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/38906) you can see:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 bash -c 'case b in [A-Z]) echo yes; esac'
yes
```

while using character class gave you nothing:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 bash -c 'case b in [[:upper:]]) echo yes; esac'
```

The caret `^`, if place at the beginning of `Bracket Expression` will negate the match of expression. `[^[:alpha:]]` will match any characters, which don't belong to `[:alpha:]` characters class:

```
$ case 1 in [^[:alpha:]]) echo yes;; esac       
yes
```