# alphabetical expansion order for *

Tags: shell, shell-script, locale, posix

When I'm using a POSIX compliant shell (es: dash, bash, zsh, ...) can I be sure that `*` will always expand in alphabetical order (dictated by `LC_COLLATE`)?

example:

```
$ echo 1 > file_a
$ echo 2 > file_b
$ echo 3 > file_c
$ cat *
1
2
3
```

Comment: See also [What is the sort order when using conditional operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271640/87770), which has a little more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the sort order when using conditional operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271640/what-is-the-sort-order-when-using-conditional-operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03), and you're safe to rely on it.

Another note that you want to set your locale to `C` to get consistent behavior. In locale with collation elements have the same sorting order, you will have [strange result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/38906).

On GNU system with UTF-8 locale:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2461' '\U2460' | sort
②
①
```

or:

```
$ printf '%s\n' A B a b | sort
a
A
b
B
```

Setting to `C` locale:

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2461' '\U2460' | LC_ALL=C sort
①
②

$ printf '%s\n' A B a b | LC_ALL=C sort
A
B
a
b
```

Some shells even do not support multibyte characters like `dash`, `mksh` or support but will choke on invalid sequences of bytes like `yash`.

Comment: Another reason to stick to `LC_COLLATE=C` is that some shells don't support multibyte characters in pattern matching (e.g. dash, mksh).

Comment: @Gilles: Ah, right, it's fair enough. I added it to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The normative answer can be found here:

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the
>   pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, **sorted
>   according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale**.
>
> - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_02