# Would cat *.txt concatenate files in alphabetical order?

Tags: cat

Let's say that I have 3 files in a directory:

apple.txt:

```
apple
```

beehive.txt:

```
beehive
```

zebra.txt:

```
zebra
```

If I concatenate this files with:

`cat *.txt > all_files.txt`

I do get:

```
apple
beehive
zebra
```

(I tested it on 5 files too, and I get the same behavior),

But my is this behavior guaranteed?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272224/117599

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the POSIX shell specification of [Filename Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13)

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale.

So unless you have an unusual collation sequence in your locale, you can depend on it being alphabetical.

Comment: Nitpick: Lexicographical.

Comment: @Kusalananda If the names only contains letters, as in the example in the question, alphabetical == lexicographical.