# doesn't work the bash script to check given single character is in lower case or uppercase

Tags: bash, shell

I write below shell script to check whether given character is in uppercase or lowercase..

```
read d
case $d in
[a-z]) echo "Character is in Lowercase";;
[A-Z]) echo "Character is in Uppercase";;
esac
```

But when I enter any case in Uppercase it displays the output "charecter is in Lowercase"
I just want to create simple script with basic programming.
Is there any solution??

Comment: please format your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: The script, as it stands now, works for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I enter any case in Uppercase"?

Comment: Iteresting. I always get lowercase in bash, but it works in dash, ksh, and zsh.

Comment: Correction : When i enter any uppercase letter as an input then also it gives output "Character is in Lowercase"

Comment: Isn't it a matter of collation order? See for example [Why does \[A-Z\] match lowercase letters in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash)

Comment: on bash, `Z` gives uppercase and all other gives lowercase... if you interchange the two statements, `a` gives lowercase and every other letter gives uppercase.. I think it may be because case does [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) and not regex matching

Comment: See steeldriver's link. Insert as second line: `LC_COLLATE=C`