# In shell script case statement unable to recognize upper case letters

Tags: shell-script

I have the following shell script

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter any character: \c"
read value

case $value in
    [a-z] )
        echo You have entered a lower case alphabet;;
    [A-Z] )
        echo You have entered an upper case alphabet;;
    [0-9] )
        echo You have entered a number;;
    [?] )
        echo You have entered a special character;;
    [*] )
        echo Unknown value;;
esac
```

Here, when I enter a upper case letter like

```
K
```

I get the output

```
You have entered a lower case alphabet
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does \[A-Z\] match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you need to set `LANG` as `C`

In terminal type

```
LANG=C
```

The `LANG` environment variable indicates the language/locale and encoding, where `C` is the language setting

Comment: Note that setting `$LANG` won't help if `$LC_COLLATE` or `$LC_ALL` is otherwise set. `LC_ALL=C`  would ensure the `C` locale is used.

Comment: Note that with `LANG=C`/`LC_ALL=C`, it would fail to recognise `É` as an uppercase letter or `π` as a lowercase one for instance. See `[[:upper:]]`/`[[:lower:]]` for characters considered uppercase/lowercase in the current locale.

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with *steeldriver*'s collation link, the solution is to use sets as defined in `man tr`.

Also, a good reference for `[[` vs `[`  [Wooledge, GLOBS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and why the following code may still fail with only [

```
  1 #! /bin/bash
  2 
  3 echo -e "Enter any character: \c"
  4 read -rN 1 value
  5 echo
  6 
  7 case $value in
  8     [[:lower:]] )
  9         echo You have entered a lower case alphabet;;
 10     [[:upper:]] )
 11         echo You have entered an upper case alphabet;;
 12     [[:digit:]] )
 13         echo You have entered a number;;
 14     [?] )
 15         echo You have entered a special character;;
 16     [*] )
 17         echo Unknown value;;
 18 esac
```

From wooledge link above:

> Ranges
>
> Globs can specify a range or class of characters, using square
>   brackets. This gives you the ability to match against a set of
>   characters. For example:
>
> [abcd]    Matches a or b or c or d
>
> [a-d]     The same as above, if globasciiranges is set or your locale is C or
>   POSIX. Otherwise, implementation-defined.
>
> [!aeiouAEIOU]    Matches any character except a, e, i, o, u and their uppercase
>   counterparts
>
> [[:alnum:]]   Matches any alphanumeric character in the current locale (letter or
>   number)
>
> [[:space:]]   Matches any whitespace character
>
> [![:space:]]   Matches any character that is not whitespace
>
> [[:digit:]_.]     Matches any digit, or _ or .

For info on globasciiranges : [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Comment: Rather than making matters this much complex, a simple terminal writing `LANG=C` is much better. And steeldriver's link explains why `LANG=C` will work