# how to check if FQDN host-name is with only small letters

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

we want to check the hostname on machines
the rule should be like this:

each hostname must be only with small letters
each hostname is FQDN

we try this

```
hostname=master01.nassa.com
[[ $hostname  =~ ^[a-z.a-z.a-z]+$ ]] && hostname is ok
```

but in spite the hostname is valid , it isn't print "hostname is ok"

what is the right syntax , where we are wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is somehow wrong and the part after `&&` misses `echo`. 
Instead of writting complex regexs to validate the hostname you can consider to do the opposite:

```
hostname=master01.naSsa.com
[[ $hostname  =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo "hostname is not ok"
hostname is not ok
```

Or

```
hostname=master01.nassa.com
[[ $hostname  =~ [A-Z] ]] || echo "hostname is ok"
hostname is ok
```

Moreover to avoid complex situation you better define locale to C or posix using `LC_ALL=C`
See : [Why does [A-Z] match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

For a `/bin/sh` solution:

```
hostname=master01.nassa.com

case $hostname in
    *[A-Z]*)
        echo 'Not ok' ;;
    *)
        echo 'Ok'
esac
```

The "Not ok" branch is taken if the value of `$hostname` contains any uppercase characters (this may depend on your locale settings), while the "Ok" branch is taken if the "Not ok" branch isn't taken.

This is similar to the `bash`-specific (and also `ksh` and `zsh`)

```
if [[ "$hostname" == *[A-Z]* ]]; then
    echo 'Not ok'
else
    echo 'Ok'
fi
```

Your test with the regular expression `^[a-z.a-z.a-z]+$` is identical to a test with `^[a-z.]+$` (since a `[...]` character class matches a single character and repeated `a-z` inside it won't make a difference).   This will actually do what you *say* it does, which is to allow only hostnames with lowercase letters (and dots).  The issue is that your hostname also contains digits.  To allow for these too, you would have to use `^[a-z0-9.]+$`.  In this case though, it may be easier to test for the smaller set of characters that are *not* allowed, which is what I do above.

Comment: very nice answer , well done

Answer (score 1):

```
hostname=master01.nassa.com
[[ "$hostname"  =~ ^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$ ]] && echo hostname is ok
```

is your example with some bugs fixed but for more accurite validation look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation