# Wildcards/Globbing: Are character ranges problematic?

Tags: wildcards, posix, locale, portability

In [The Linux Command Line](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11724436-the-linux-command-line) William Shotts claims that character ranges can be problematic. See the relevant excerpt below, *emphasis is mine*.

> **Character Ranges**
>
> If you are coming from another Unix-like environment or have been reading
> some other books on this subject, you may have encountered the `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` character range notations. These are traditional Unix notations and worked in older versions of Linux as well. *They can still work, but you have to be careful with them because they will not produce the expected results unless properly configured. For now, you should avoid using them and use character classes instead*.

What is he talking about in the last couple of sentences? What do the POSIX standards say about this?

Comment: The book is freely available for download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/).

Comment: wildcards are typically used in the area of filename generation; do you see any connection to variables for your question? (I don't, but it's your question)

Comment: @JeffSchaller My suspicion stems from the second paragraph [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html). If you think the tag isn't appropriate here, please let me know and I'll remove it. Also, feel free to remove it yourself. Thanks.

Comment: The reference is probably to locale-dependence: see for example [Why does `[A-Z]` match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, this is very promising. In my two systems `LC_COLLATE` isn't even defined. It would be helpful to know more about this variable.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` might not be defined explicitly - what does the output of the `locale` command say though?

Comment: @steeldriver [Here](https://pastebin.com/tAYbRXkX) it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That most likely refers to locales having uppercase and lowercase characters ordered in alternation, instead of first one, then the other:

```
$ echo "$LANG"
en_US.UTF-8
$ touch a A z Z
$ ls
A  Z  a  z
$ bash -c 'echo [a-z]'
a A z
```

However, the appropriate character class works:

```
$ bash -c 'echo [[:lower:]]'
a z
```

But might also match more than just `a` to `z`:

```
$ LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
$ touch ä Ä ö Ö
$ bash -c 'echo [[:lower:]]'
a z ä ö
```

If you want to avoid that, and only match the English lowercase letters `a` to `z`, Bash in particular has an option to interpret the ranges in the ASCII order:

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -s globasciiranges; echo [a-z]'
a z
```

And you can always force the default collating order:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C bash -c 'echo [a-z]'
a z
```

---

As for what POSIX says, it seems to me that ranges in bracket expressions are left undefined in locales other than the default POSIX one. The pattern matching description refers to the [regex description of bracket expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05), which says:

> In the POSIX locale, a range expression represents the set of collating elements that fall between two elements in the collation sequence, inclusive. In other locales, a range expression has unspecified behavior: strictly conforming applications shall not rely on whether the range expression is valid, or on the set of collating elements matched.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how `bash -c 'echo [a-z]'` works. If I don't run the commands in the specific order that you do in your answer, it just echoes `[a-z]`. Can you shed some light on that? Also, is there a way to check the definition of each character class?

Comment: @GitGud `[a-z]` is a glob pattern, just like `foo*`; if you don't have any file starting with foo in the current dir, `echo foo*` will just echo `foo*`; if you don't have any file named `a`, `b`, `c`, etc in the current dir, `echo [a-z]` will echo just `[a-z]`.

Comment: Ah! Of course! Got it. Thanks @UncleBilly

Comment: @ikkachu Just to make sure you didn't miss my second question: is there a way to check the definition of each character class?

Comment: @GitGud, I'm not really familiar with the internals of locales, so I can't say.

Comment: Even worse, "unspecified behavior" means that it can change at any time.  As of Ubuntu 20.04, the lower case ranges in the en_US.UTF-8 locale behaves just like the POXIS or C locale, unlike in the above example which outputs (some) uppercase.  (End of the range UC was always missed, an implementation error most likely).