# find replace and append extension to a string

Tags: sed

Hi I would like to use `sed` for the following task:

I have a shell variable called `tor=hello:there/you/are/here` and I am putting an underscore everywhere I need it to transform this shell variable in a file name with underscores like so:

`sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' <<< $tor`

The result is this one:

`hello_there_you_are_here`

But I would like to add an extension like this:

`hello_there_you_are_here.sif`

How can I add an extension with sed at the end of the line ?

Comment: Try `sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' -e 's/$/.sif/' <<< $tor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user fpmurphy pointed out in comments, all you need is to add "a line of code" to Sed that says "match the end-of-line and put a `.sif` there". Since the "line of code" is added with `-e`, you get

```
sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:].-]/_/g' -e 's/$/.sif/' <<< "$tor"
```

Notice I have made some modifications. Always quote variable expansions, use `"$tor"` instead of `$tor`, as this is [good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767), although not really required in the present case because Bash does not perform word splitting or globbing on here-strings. Also, `[:alnum:]` is a POSIX class that matches `[A-Za-z0-9]` in a standard locale, so it is more reliable. See, for example, [Why should 'Character Classes' be preferred over 'Character Ranges'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72761), but take this as a small side-note.

Comment: Or simpler: `sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:].-]/_/g' <<< "$tor".sif`

Comment: why always quote variable expansions?

Comment: @alex I have expanded on that claim. I didn't know it, but with here-strings you don't really need to quote, but in lots of cases your shell scripts can have problems if you leave variables unquoted, you don't lose anything by quoting.