# Debian thinks my file system is encoded as ISO-8859-1

Tags: debian, locale, character-encoding, defaults

This may not be the appropriate site for this question, because it's more a complaint than a question, but here goes.

Today I updated my computer from Mint 15 to Debian 7.6. And after I'd done that, my computer thought that all the existing filenames were encoded as ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. So, for instance, filenames containing "à" now got displayed as "Ã " and so on.
Turns out I needed to tell my system *explicitly* that the file system uses UTF-8, by putting `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in my .bashrc file.

And the question is, why? Why should something like that be necessary in this day and age, 2014? The default was UTF-8 for Mint, obviously; why should Debian be any different? What would cause Debian to use such an obscure and outdated default, even if I told it at install time what I wanted my locale to be, and /etc/locale.gen only contains `en_US.UTF8 UTF8` as the only (uncommented) line. And do I need to remember to edit the .bashrc file for every new user account that I create from now on to edit the export line in?

Answer (score 2):

The [default locale on Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html#_the_locale) is in a UTF-8 encoding, at least since wheezy (I don't remember when it switched). So you must have chosen some non-default setting during the installation.

> putting export `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in my .bashrc file.

That's not going to work, because [`.bashrc` is the wrong file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085). An environment variable defined there only applies to programs launched from a terminal.

The right place to define this environment variable is `/etc/environment` to make it a system setting or `~/.pam_environment` to make it a per-user setting. Both files are [read at login time](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pam_env&sektion=8&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) (by all login methods).

The specific [locale variable](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=locale&sektion=7&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) for the character encoding is `LC_CTYPE`. Setting `LANG` sets all settings, including `LC_COLLATE` which [can have surprising consequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges). You should set only `LC_CTYPE`.

So remove the `LANG` setting from your `.bashrc` and add `LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8` where it belongs, i.e. in `/etc/environment` or `~/.pam_environment`.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to remember to edit the .bashrc file for every new user account that I create from now on to edit the export line in?

The best idea in this case is to put it in a system wide file; first check to see if it's already being set somewhere:

```
grep -R LANG /etc
```

You may or may not want to change anything there.

[Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145615/25985) probably has the most effective place to set this, but I'm leaving what I have here partly to explain what he means by "read at login time (by all login methods)".

You can create a `ZZ-local.sh` file and put it in `/etc/profile.d`.  The files there get sourced in lexicographical order when a user logs in, so `ZZ` should override anything previous.  The file does not need to be executable or contain a shebang, so the one line `export LANG=...` should be fine.

Some GUI login display managers *don't* read `.profile` -- e.g., lightdm (you may have noticed one of the `grep` hits to do with this; lightdm exports `$LANG` in an init script).  If that's the case, you'll want to do the same thing as just described WRT `/etc/profile.d`, but for `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`.  In fact, there's no harm in:

```
ln -s /etc/profile.d/ZZ-local.sh /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ZZ-local
```

Symlinking the two files.  Just keep in mind that this may mean it will get sourced twice in succession, although if all you are doing is setting `$LANG`, that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did some experimenting and by now I don't have any `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in my .bashrc files, but the encoding is still OK, even after rebooting. So I don't know what I did.

Comment: The default is UTF-8 as of wheezy (and maybe some earlier releases, I don't remember when UTF-8 became the default but it definitely is the default for a wheezy installation).

Answer (score 1):

First, I am surprised that you are able to update Mint 15 to Debian 7.6. They after all are different distributions.

I assume Debian made the decision to use ISO 8859.1 because you are located in Europe and answered some question to that effect regarding the locale.

Comment: Actually I did a "mostly fresh" install, erasing the system partition first but leaving the home partition alone. But I did say I wanted the en_US.UTF8 locale when installing, so that can't have been the problem.