# Meaning of "[--0]" in a glob pattern

Tags: wildcards

I was reading about "Glob" and "Globbing Pathnames", and I found this strange (to me) part in [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html):

> "[--0]" matches the three characters '-', '.', '0', since '/' cannot be matched.

I am confused! How do two dashes and a `0` match `.`? What is the role of the `/` character here? Is this is a bug in man page?

Comment: I found the answer to my question, when I was typing it! :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the beginning of that paragraph in [that man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), '-' character, **when put between two characters**, represents a range of characters, and also, '-' character, **when put as first or last character between brackets**, has its literal meaning. So, the first dash really means a '-' character, and the second dash is a range specifier. So the whole pattern consists of all the characters between '-' and '0', which, in the C/POSIX locale (but generally not in others) are:

```
-
.
/
0
```

and **since '/' cannot be matched**, the pattern matches three characters '-', '.', '0'.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with man pages themselves: it's a description of the syntax of glob patterns, which the man page you're looking at is about.

In a glob pattern, brackets delimit a character set. For example `[abc]` matches any of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`. The pattern `fo[abc]` matches `foa`, `fob` and `foc` (but not e.g. `foo`, or `fo`, or `foab`).

Inside the brackets, the character `-` has a special meaning: it is used to form a character range. So rather than matching `0`, `-` or `9`, the pattern `[0-9]` matches any digit. Ranges can be combined with other ranges and lone characters; for example `[A-Za-z_]` in the ASCII encoding matches any letter or an underscore.

The minus sign is only interpreted as a range indicator when this would be syntactically sensible: if it's the first or last character inside the brackets, or if it comes immediately after another range, `-` stands for itself. So in `[--0]`, the first `-` stands for itself and the second `-` is a range indicator, therefore this pattern matches any character that is between `-` and `0` in the current locale.

In the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, this range covers the following 4 characters: `-`, `.`, `/`, `0`. The character `/` cannot appear inside a file name, because it is always interpreted as a directory separator; therefore the pattern `[--0]` matches only the 3 characters `-`, `.` and `0`.

Note that in locales other than ASCII, the pattern could match a different set of characters. [The effect of locale setting on character ranges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges) is somewhat variable between systems and applications.

Most regular expressions engines use the same syntax for character ranges as shell glob patterns, with two differences:

- In a glob pattern, if the first character after the opening bracket is a `!`, the pattern matches all characters that are *not* in the set. In a regular expression, the character `^` plays the same role. Some shells support `^` as well as `!`.
- Some regular expression variants allow `\` to make the next character lose its special meaning, e.g. `[\[\]\-a]` matches `[`, `]`, `-` or `a`. In other regular expression variants and in glob patterns, a backslash in character sets has no special meaning. If `]` is in the set, it must come first (it's impossible to specify an empty set: `[]` is an incomplete pattern, matching a closing bracket or any character that comes afterwards).