# Konsole displays ?? instead of ↑ and ↓ in midnight commander

Tags: mc, konsole

In midnight commander, changing the appearance via menu, selecting the skin `sand256.ini` etc. on many Linux setups gives nice colors.

After reversing the sort order of file listing, ideally this is indicated by a real arrow, as if **mc** was a GUI.

But, the skins kill the special characters and display ??? instead of **↑** if you change the skin. Also double lines are wrongly displayed as QQ or whatever.

I saw **mc** with proper arrows ↑ on my very Manjaro installation but changed some Konsole settings or whatever and now cannot get it back to a proper arrow display that worked just minutes before.

I also used a line in `~/.bashrc`, `export LANG=en` to kill the terrible translation and **aspell** error message.

Below graphical characters from the skin.ini is displayed wrongly:

```
[widget-common]
    sort-sign-up = ↑
    sort-sign-down = ↓

[widget-panel]
    hiddenfiles-sign-show = •
    hiddenfiles-sign-hide = ○
    history-prev-item-sign = «
    history-next-item-sign = »
    history-show-list-sign = ^

[widget-scollbar]
    first-vert-char = ↑
    last-vert-char = ↓
    first-horiz-char = «
    last-horiz-char = »
    current-char = ■
    background-char = ▒
```

Comment: sudo localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i de_DE de_DE.utf8

has no real effect.

Comment: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts: http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/134981/midnight-manager and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135020/midnight-manager.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to this question.       P.S. If you plan on being a member of the Stack Exchange community, I suggest that you *register* your merged account.

Answer (score 2):

I now could reproduce the situation and describe how to have a proper display in mc:

Create 2 Konsole (i.e. the KDE x-term emulator shipping with many distros) profiles "badstart" and "proper" via "settings/manage profiles".
in "badstart" , click "environment/edit" and put in there:
TERM=xterm-256color

Set "badstart" as the "default profile" (a heart icon will indicate it).

The "proper" profile just leave untouched, just rename it to "proper" after creating a new profile (it will have TERM=xterm).

Then a menu-entry for mc is needed via kmenuedit: 
command: mc , enable "advanced tab/run in terminal".

For some weird reason this works only if mc is started from such a K-menu entry, but not if the standard Konsole starter-icon is clicked and mc is typed manually inside the Konsole-text-window bash prompt.

Now, if mc is run via from the KDE menu, it will show up the line-characters messed up (profile "badstart" is active).

Then in Konsole-menu, click: setting/switch profile --> select "proper"

Then by way of some unfathomable automagic, mc will look excellent and all skins display properly.

I presume it has to do with locale misconfiguration of some sort, like Gilles correctly pointed out in the other answer.

Overriding locale settings by having a line in `~/.bashrc`

```
export LANG=en
```

is a rather poor idea. In Manjaro-settings (not "system-settings"), most "locale" options can be configured via a GUI, allowing non-English keyboard users to have the English language across the OS except keyboard-layout.

Once **export LANG=en**  was killed in the `~/.bashrc`, it was even possible to have mc properly displayed in the "badstart" profile. 
This way, one can have a single-click-256color-mc started, which is hard to do in many KDE configurations.

Answer (score 1):

> I also used LANG=en to kill the terrible translation and aspell error message.

That's the problem. The `en` locale uses the [latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set, which doesn't line drawing characters or arrows. To get these characters, you need a Unicode locale, such as `en_US.utf8`.

If all you wanted was to have messages in English, don't set `LANG`: English is the default language. Setting `LANG` is not a good idea anyway because it includes the collation locale, which [can have surprising results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges). Set `LC_CTYPE` to indicate the character set and encoding (but it's often set automatically by your terminal and best left alone). Set `LC_MESSAGES` to control the language of messages.

See also [What should I set my locale to and what are the implications of doing so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129)