# In grep command, can I change [:digit:] to [0-9]?

Tags: grep

Will `grep [0-9]` work in the same way as `grep [:digit:]`?

Comment: Can you please explaina bit ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/891741/4957508 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode

Answer (score 17):

No, `[0-9]` is **not** the same as `[:digit:]`.

`[0-9]` matches the numerals 0 to 9.

`[:digit:]` matches 0 to 9, and numerals in non-western languages as well (e.g. Eastern Arabic).

Comment: Please, could you provide a specific name for, or a link (with a table) to, the (preferably) shortest such character set?

Comment: Also are you sure that '[0-9]' _always_ matches _only_  0 to 9?  Perhaps in some other character set, '[0-9]' pulls in other chars.

Comment: @agc `[0-9]` matches the **literal** ASCII characters "0", "1", …, "9", the same way that `[A-Z]` matches ASCII characters "A" through "Z". These patterns are restricted to the ASCII character set by definition. On the other hand, `[:digit:]` designates a broader **character class**, which also includes Unicode characters for digits in other languages.

Comment: `[charX-charY]` implies low level library code that looks up the character code for *charX* in the current character set, and counts from there up to the code for *charY*.   `[A-Z]` on an ASCII system matches 26 codes: {65,...90}. EBCDIC matches 41 codes: {193,...233}.   `[:upper:]` would always match only 26 codes on ASCII, EBCDIC, etc.   Thankfully, `[0-9]` matches 10 codes with ASCII or EBCDIC codes -- what's uncertain is whether any character sets exist (or shall exist) for which `[0-9]` matches more than or less than 10 codes.  If such a set exists, `[:digit:]` is useful.

Comment: Abligh's answer below says it so much better, so "never mind..."

Comment: @Guido Actually `[A-Z]` matches more than ASCII letters sometimes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges On the other hand, I think all extant locales have `[0-9]` match only the ASCII digits.

Answer (score 3):

You can change `[[:digit:]]` to `[0-9]` - note `[:digit:]` is inside `[…]`. This depends on the encoding of the input. If it is ASCII, I don't think there will be a problem. With other encodings, the digits may not be contiguous, or the byte range maybe different. You could also miss special numbers in other writing systems.

Answer (score 3):

To be precise `[0-9]` is only guaranteed to be equivalent to `[:digit:]` if:

- the regexp parser supports `[:digit:]` (i.e. if it does not, then the existing `[:digit:]` probably doesn't do what you think it does), and:
- the input character set is one such as ASCII where the only digits are the characters `0` - `9` and they are adjacent. This might not be true in (e.g.) unicode (where the digits may include characters other than the digits `0` - `9`), or even in other 8 bit character sets where `0` - `9` may not be adjacent (as it happens in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) the digits `0` - `9` are adjacent).

Examples of unicode exceptions are shown [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). As you can see the set of unicode characters in the category 'Number, Digit, Decimal' includes rather more than the 10 ASCII digits matched by `[0-9]`; it includes arabic indic, extended arabic, ngo, etc.

More information on numerals in unicode can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode#Numerals_by_script).

Comment: The ASCII digits are adjacent and in order in all extant locales, so `[0-9]` is a safe way to match them.

Comment: @Gilles they are adjacent in ASCII but not in all 8 bit character sets. And it is not true that all *digits* are adjacent in Unicode (as there are digits other than `[0-9]`)

Answer (score 1):

**'[:digit:]'** is *theoretically* more portable, the advantage being that it would not depend on one's local character set clumping digits all together.

Related example: With '[:upper:]' vs '[A-Z]' there's no difference in ASCII, but there *is* a difference on an old IBM [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) system, where '[A-Z]' would span 41 chars not 26, (EBCDIC codes 193-233) and would therefore match EBCDIC "}\" et al.