# man gives the error about locale

Tags: man, locale

I have

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
C
en_GB.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

But `man` gives the error:

```
$ man
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
What manual page do you want?
```

If I set the `LC_ALL`, the error disappears:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 man
What manual page do you want?
```

But I don't want to set `LC_ALL` because I set some `LC_` to the other locale.

How to solve this problem with `man`?

Comment: Try setting your locales to "ru_RU.utf8" not "ru_RU.UTF-8".

Comment: `LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 man` cause no error. Thus, IMHO, `man` just considers not all `LC_` are set. Maybe it need `LC_ALL` mandatory is set, but this is stupid behavior, I think...

Comment: Negative, LC_ALL is not required, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all?rq=1  I looked at my locale settings and everything but LC_ALL is set for me.  Mine are all set to "en_US.utf8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code in the source to `man` for Debian squeeze:

```
/* initialise the locale */
    if (!setlocale (LC_ALL, "") && !getenv ("MAN_NO_LOCALE_WARNING"))
        /* Obviously can't translate this. */
        error (0, 0, "can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG "
                 "are correct");
    setenv ("MAN_NO_LOCALE_WARNING", "1", 1);
```

Try setting the environment variable `MAN_NO_LOCALE_WARNING` to 1 to see if that helps.  I'm not sure why `setlocale (LC_ALL, "")` is failing, according to the documentation for `setlocale()`:

```
The return value is NULL if the request cannot be honored.
```