# How to change the language for date command?

Tags: date, conky

I'm using `vnstat` together with `conky`. To show the monthly traffic I'm mixing `vnstat` and `grep` to find the month. The command to collect the data is

```
${execi 3600 vnstat -m -i wlan0 | grep "$(date "+%h")" | awk '{print $3 $4}'}
```

but the problem is that `vnstat` returns the month in English (Dec for December) and `date` returns it in Portuguese (Dez for Dezembro).

So my command is not working for the monthly traffic. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to export `LANG` to `date`. Assuming that `execi` invokes a POSIX-compliant shell to do the heavy lifting (note: I don't know if it does or not, your mileage may vary), something like the following should work:

```
${execi 3600 vnstat -m -i wlan0 | grep "$(LC_ALL=C date "+%h")" | awk '{print $3 $4}'}
```

Comment: Setting `LANG` only overrides a locale setting through `LANG`. It doesn't override a locale setting through `LC_TIME`.

Answer (score 3):

To run a command in a don't-bother-me-about-locales mode, set the environment variable `LC_ALL`. This overrides all locale settings. The don't-bother-me locale is called `C` (or `POSIX`, they are synonyms).

```
export LC_ALL=C; vnstat -m -i wlan0 | grep "$(date "+%h")" | awk '{print $3 $4}'
```

This sets all error messages to English, all dates to US dates, sorting to byte order, and printable characters to ASCII.

See [set LC_* but not LC_ALL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all/15334#15334) for more details.