# Is there a way to use a PT_BR locale in an English installation of Debian?

Tags: x11, locale, dead-keys

I'm Brazilian but when I installed Debian on my machine I set the language to English (US). I prefer to keep my menus and error messages in English because they are more googable (and the translations aren't always the best...). Anyway, this had the unfortunate consequence of making it annoying to write text in Portuguese because in the `en_US` locale (with a "US international with dead keys" keyboard layout) typing <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> results in a `Ć` instead of the `Ç` that I want. Is there a way to make my "typing locale" be PT_BR while still keeping all my menus in English and the US keyboard layout with dead keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to change the dead keys without changing the keyboard layout is to set the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable to `pt_BR.utf8`. I did this by adding the following line to my `.profile`.

```
export LC_CTYPE='pt_BR.utf8'
```

There are also other `LC_` variables that you can set if you want. The `locale` command shows a list of them, [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/envvar.html#tag_002_002) describes what they do and `locale -a` says what locales are currently available in the system.

That said, in order for this to work, both the `en_US.utf8` and `pt_BR.utf8` locales need to be installed in the system. To make sure this is the case, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

In the first screen, it will ask what locales you want to generate for the system (so select both `en_US.utf8` and `pt_BR.utf8`) and in the second screen it asks what should be the default system language  (choose English).

Comment: Setting `LC_CTYPE` doesn't affect the keyboard layout.

Comment: @Gilles: Why is setting LC_CTYPE is working for me then? The ç works when I set that variable to "pt_BR.utf8" and goes back to being ć when I set it to "en_US.utf8". And if I run `locale`, everything is set to english except LC_CTYPE

Comment: Oh, did you mean that you want to retain the US keyboard layout, and only change the dead key compositions? I didn't understand that from your question. In this case, your answer is mostly right, except that setting `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` is not necessary and has the nasty side effect of [setting `LC_COLLATE`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all/15334#15334). Just set `LC_CTYPE` to `pt_BR.utf8` in `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`.

Comment: OK. In my case the assignments to LANG and LANGUAGE are redundant so I guess its a good idea to leave them out. But that link you gave is confusing me. Right now, all my environment variables are set to `en_US.utf8` - should they have been `C` instead? (Is this what choosing "none" as the language in dpkg-reconfigure does? Does this make my menus appear in english?)

Comment: C is the default locale and in practice that means English and ASCII. Since you want English with Unicode, leave most locale variables unset (this is equivalent to setting them to `C`), and set `LC_CTYPE` (the `utf8` part is the most important; the part of `LC_CTYPE` before the `.` only affects a few programs, one of which is the input method you're using where it affects dead keys).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: What does this command do? I don't want to change everything, just how my keyboard input is treated...

Comment: You can copy/paste from here, It reconfigure locales package, when you reconfiure it, you can add or remove other locales and "set your default locale", you need to set default locale.

Comment: but if I change my default locale to pt_BR its also going to make all my menus appear in Portuguese isn't it? I don't want that.

Comment: No, when you change your locale change everything, But you can have keyboard layout and some other....