# Case sensitivity in square-bracket globbing

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, locale

Normally, bash globbing is case sensitive:

```
$ echo c*
casefix.pike cdless chalices.py charconv.py chocolate.pike circum.py clip.pike cpustats.pike crop.pike cwk2txt.py
$ echo C*
CarePackage.md ChocRippleCake.md Clips
```

Using square brackets doesn't seem to change this:

```
$ echo [c]*
casefix.pike cdless chalices.py charconv.py chocolate.pike circum.py clip.pike cpustats.pike crop.pike cwk2txt.py
$ echo [C]*
CarePackage.md ChocRippleCake.md Clips
```

It still doesn't change it if a hyphen is used:

```
$ echo [c-c]*
casefix.pike cdless chalices.py charconv.py chocolate.pike circum.py clip.pike cpustats.pike crop.pike cwk2txt.py
$ echo [C-C]*
CarePackage.md ChocRippleCake.md Clips
```

But the letters are interspersed:

```
$ echo [B-C]*
CarePackage.md casefix.pike cdless chalices.py charconv.py chocolate.pike ChocRippleCake.md circum.py clip.pike Clips cpustats.pike crop.pike cwk2txt.py
$ echo [b-c]*
beehive-anthem.txt bluray2mkv.pike branch branchcleanup.pike burdayim.pike casefix.pike cdless chalices.py charconv.py chocolate.pike circum.py clip.pike cpustats.pike crop.pike cwk2txt.py
```

This suggests that the hyphen is using a locale order, "AaBbCcDd". So: is there any way to glob for all files that begin with an uppercase letter?

Comment: Also note the gotcha that [A-Z] matches every lowercase letter except ‘z’!

Comment: [Why does `[A-Z]` match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/44425)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In bash version 4.3 and later, there is a shopt option called `globasciiranges` :

According to [shopt builtin gnu man pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

> globasciiranges
>   If set, range expressions used in pattern matching
>   bracket expressions (see Pattern Matching) behave as if in the
>   traditional C locale when performing comparisons. That is, the current
>   locale’s collating sequence is not taken into account, so ‘b’ will not
>   collate between ‘A’ and ‘B’, and upper-case and lower-case ASCII
>   characters will collate together.

As a result you can

```
$ shopt -s globasciiranges 
$ echo [A-Z]*
```

Use `shopt -u` for disabling.

Another way is to change locale to C. 
You can do this temporarily using a subshell:

```
$ ( LC_ALL=C ; printf '%s\n' [A-Z]*; )
```

You will get the results you need, and when the sub shell is finished, the locale of your main shell remains unchanged to whatever was before.

Another alternative is instead of `[A-Z]` to use brace expansion `{A..Z}` together with `nullglob` bash shopt option.

By enabling the `nullglob` option, if a pattern is not matched during pathname expansion, a null string is returned instead of the pattern itself.
As a result this one will work as expected:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob;printf '%s\n' {A..Z}*
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I can't use `[[:upper:]]` because I actually want just part of the alphabet, but this works.

Comment: @rosuav Welcome. Check also the sub shell alternative.

Comment: _“if enabled equals to C locale”_ -- do you mean it affects the locale used for globbing and nothing else? (A reference link would have been helpful -- the best I can find is https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html, but I would have preferred a list of all shell options, but globasciiranges is missing from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin; also the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash handles this issue extensively.) Also from version 4.3.

Comment: @PjTrail See my edit with a reference link to all shopt options . Also you can run `man bash` in your terminal and search (using `/`) for globasciiranges.

Comment: Wouldn't `LC_ALL=C printf '%s\n' [A-Z]*` work for your second solution - without a subshell? BTW: there's a typo: `nullblog`, but it's too few characters for me to correct it.

Comment: @joe No , this syntax did not worked in my tests. You can try it your self.

Comment: The bash shell is still undergoing changes, and the character ranges have been returned back to the LC_COLLATE=C behavior (at some point prior to Nov 2020). The man page documentation (on Ubuntu 20.04) has not been updated, and still refers to locale for ranges. The LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"'s "broken" lower case ranges which returned upper case results except for the end of the range ([a-c] matches aAbBc), now just return the abc results, and the broken workarounds like [a-C] are now illegal syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You can write the all the uppercase letters just fine like:

```
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*
```

or use can use the named character class `[:upper:]` to represent all uppercase letters in your current `locale`:

```
[[:upper:]]*
```

---

As you have noticed, while using range like `[B-C]` the upper and lower case for same alphabetic character are being arranged adjacently (according to collation order of the `locale`).

Answer (score 3):

Including “unintuitive” characters in character ranges, such as including lowercase letters in a range whose boundaries are uppercase letters, is due to the `LC_COLLATE` locale setting. `LC_COLLATE` is supposed to indicate sorting order, but it does a poor job of it (sorting strings is more complex than what locales can do) and you're better off without it. I recommend to remove `LC_COLLATE` from your locale settings. If you're setting `LANG`, or `LANGUAGE`, don't do that and set only the ones you need: `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_TIME`.

For more background about locales, see [What should I set my locale to and what are the implications of doing so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129) and [set LC_* but not LC_ALL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all/15334#15334)

To get reliable results in a script regardless of the user's settings, set `LC_ALL=C`.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
shopt -u nocaseglob
```

From bash man page:

```
>     nocaseglob
>         If  set,  bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive
>         fashion when performing pathname expansion (see Pathname
>          Expansion above).
```

If you set 'globasciiranges' I do not know what will happen
to non-ascii characters like utf-8

Answer (score 0):

echo [cC]* should do what you want, similarly [A-Za-z]*

I'm here because globbing on my system has just *stopped* being case sensitive, so loads of my scripts no longer work as they should :-(

Comment: That's the opposite to what I'm seeing. But check the other answers for suggestions.